# neo4j deleting my array data

Tags: arrays, neo4j

.Hi, I'm importing data into a Neo4j graph.

I've imported "Topics", some of which have .aliases set as an array, some don't.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///home/michael/db/Aliases.csv" AS r
MATCH (t:Topic { mysql_id: toInt(r.id)})
SET t.aliases = [] + t.aliases + split(r.aliases, ';') + r.alias;
// Where t.aliases, r.aliases, or r.alias can be null.
// If any are null then the result is null, erasing the other data.
```

The problem is adding any null to an array kills the array.  The use case for this behavior is obviously ... well, null.  But whatever.

How to append possibly null values to an array in Cypher?

Thanks!

Mike

Update: I made a workaround by using three queries:

1. Create Topic and `set t.aliases = [] + r.alias` which may be null
2. Update Topic with r.aliases WHERE NOT HAS(t.aliases).
3. Update Topic with r.aliases WHERE HAS (t.aliases)

Which seems like extra work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I found on this [github issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/4734):

You can use coalesce to deal with null values:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///home/michael/db/Aliases.csv" AS r
MATCH (t:Topic { mysql_id: toInt(r.id)})
SET t.aliases = coalesce(t.aliases,[]) + split(coalesce(r.aliases,''), ';') + coalesce(r.alias,[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your "null" alias? Can't see it in your data.

You can filter them out with

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///home/michael/db/Aliases.csv" AS r
with r, filter(x in split(r.aliases, ';') WHERE not x is null) as aliases
MATCH (t:Topic { mysql_id: toInt(r.id)})
SET t.aliases2 = t.aliases + aliases, 
    t.aliases3 = + aliases;
```

Comment: Hi, sorry it wasn't clear.  `t.aliases`, `r.alias`, or `r.aliases` can be null.  I updated the example code to show better.